# Hacky Button Disabling

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I have an application that allows a user to pick one of three buttons. I don't want the button to be press-able after they click it but I also don't want the button to look all `isenabled=false` ugly. As far as I know there's no way of disabling the appearance change on the `isenabled=false` so I thought I'd use a transparent control placed over it to prevent the user from clicking it. My question is, what control should I use? Was trying `Label` but couldn't get that to fill a grid cell. Would something like `Canvas` work, or is that click-through-able?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just style the button? You can make it look what ever way you want then.

Comment: Have a look at ToggleButton. It does what you want, you just need to specify the style

Comment: You are using WPF, pretty much anything can be styled there, including the look when a button is disabled.

Comment: Couldn't you just add some logic in the buttons' handlers to make them not do anything if they've already been used?

Comment: I have styles on the button, but the disabling still changes the appearance of the button. That's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Users will still be able to click the button via the keyboard.

Comment: How do I access it's disabled appearance?

Comment: If you override the appearance on disable, you can make it not look different.

Comment: But what is the override method called?

Comment: Ya prob would have settled to this solution if I hadn't seen Vincent's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent to button to be clicked, use `IsHitTestVisible`, binding it to one  (notifying) property. It will do just what you want : if `IsHitTestVisible` is false, the mouse clics won't affect it, and it will look the same.

Comment: YES! Tried everything on this page and this worked exactly how I wanted it to. Thanks also to @akjoshi for making the post a little clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ToggleButton` and handle `Unchecked` event.
Like this:

```
private void MyToggleButton_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            MyToggleButton.IsChecked = true;
        }
```

This way, user will not be able to uncheck it once it is checked once.

Comment: Thanks man. Tried this and it allows me to press the button, it then changes appearance but doesn't allow me to repress it. I don't want it to change appearance in the first place.